# Error calling gender in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame of names which I read from a csv file. contents of the data frame is as below.

```
       NAME CURR_GENDER COUNT
1       LESLIE          N   186
2        COREY          N    86
3       KELSEY          N    52
4        DARYL          N    38
5 PRISCIANDARO          N    33
6         SUNG          N    30
```

I am trying to determine the gender using [gender](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gender/index.html) library given the name and add the output as a column to the existing data frame.

```
    csv_in <- "Names.csv"

    Names_df <- read.csv(csv_in)

    gender(Names_df$NAME,
     method = "ssa",
     years = c(1930, 2012)) %>%
     do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)
```

However, I am getting the below error. Hoping you can point out what I am doing wrong here.

> Error in gender(Names_df$NAME, method = "ssa", years = c(1930, 2012))
>   :    Data must be a character vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `Names_df$NAME` is not a character vector, but needs to be. Try running

```
Names_df$NAME <- as.character(Names_df$NAME)
```

and then trying again. 
If that doesn't work, run `class(Names_df$NAME)` and tell us what comes up.

Comment: Better yet; if that doesn't work give us a reproducible example.

Comment: Great. That is It. It works now. Thank you very much.  I just assumed that strings will be preserved as strings since I imported the data frame from csv. Guess, lesson here is to never assume :).